# Unable to ping Cisco 3750 Switch from non-directly connected device

Tags: ip, switch, vlan, cisco

I have a Cisco 3750 configured baiscally as a hub.  All ports are configured as access ports on the same vlan 10.  VLAN interface 10 was given an IP Address of 10.10.10.1, in order to connect to the switch.  I can ping the device from a directly connected router 10.10.10.99, but unable to ping the device from a different subnet 1.1.1.1.  This switch is used to connect to other devices in the site on the same 10.10.10 subnet, and I am able to ping those devices through the switch, but not the switches vlan interface.  Can anyone tell me what im missing?

I have dealt with this issue before, so I feel really stupid asking this question, and feel like I will kick myself once someone answers, but I just cannot think of whats causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need for the switch's traffic to route properly, which probably just means setting the default gateway.  Assuming that 10.10.10.99's the correct router to use to get between the subnets:

```
ip default-gateway 10.10.10.99
```

Comment: Doh... I knew I would kick myself.  I assumed default static route all 0's to 10.10.10.99 would be good enough.  Guess I needed that ip default-gateway command.  Thanks